# Invoke asynchronous method from dll via an interface in the main program

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task, invoke

I want to define a method in a DLL and call it asynchronously in my application.

This method should copy files on a USB disk if there are files to copy.

To avoid blocking the main application during this copy operation, I want to call the check and copy method from the DLL asynchronously.
Synchronous

```
//Main Program:
    private void CheckForCopyFiles()
    {
      myDLL.CheckForCopy();
    } 
//interface 
    public void CheckForCopy()
    {
        MethodInfo m = type.GetMethod("CheckForCopy");
        m.Invoke(instance, null);
    }
//DLL
    public void CheckForCopy()
    {
     // check and copy
    }
```

Now if I want to call this method asynchronously, I thought I would do the following.

```
//Main
    private async Task CheckForCopyFiles()
    {
       await myDLL.CheckForCopy();
    }
//Interface
    public async Task CheckForCopyFilesAyc()
    {
        MethodInfo m = type.GetMethod("CheckForCopyFilesAyc");
        await m.Invoke(instance, null); // Compiler error CS1061
    }
//DLL
    public async Task CheckForCopyFilesAyc()
    {
      await Task.Run(() => BackupRestore.BackupRestoreDB.CheckForAutoBackup(Parent));
    }
```

Error CS1061 "object" does not contain a definition for "GetAwaiter", and no accessible GetAwaiter extension method could be found that accepts a first argument of type "object" (possibly missing a using directive or an assembly reference).

can someone give me a hint how to define the method in DLL so that I can call the through interface in the main program?

thanks

Comment: Your code is using reflection, not interfaces. You can't make a method asynchronous by using `await`. `await` *awaits* an already executing task without blocking the calling thread. Why are you using reflection in the first place?

Comment: You should call `CheckForCopyFilesAyc`, not `CheckForCopyFiles`. If you actually use an interface, all you'd have to do is `await something.CheckForCopyFilesAyc();`. When you use reflection the result of `Invoke` is an `object` that encapsulates the actual result. In asynchronous methods, the result is always a Task-derived class. You can't use `await` on `object`. You'd have to cast it to `Task` first, eg ` await (Task)m.Invoke(instance, null);`.

Comment: Invoke yields object. Have you tried casting?

Comment: Required reading: [Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/)

Comment: TLDR; You need to use `await Task.Run(CheckForCopy);` to avoid blocking, unless there is an `async` alternative.

Comment: Hi, it is not possible to cast like await (Task)m.Invoke(instance, null); causes the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Invoke should return an object convertible to Task. Just await that.

If your private method returns void, then you'll need a custom SynchronizationContext, which is messy. It's better to have your methods return Task/Task.

```
public async Task CheckForCopyFilesAyc()
{
    MethodInfo m = type.GetMethod("CheckForCopyFilesAyc");
    await (Task) m.Invoke(instance, null); 
}
```